# Better way to use HikariCP with Hibernate in Spring Boot Project

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, connection-pooling, hikaricp

I'm a beginner, I have a simple Spring Boot project, it's my first time using a connection pool (HikariCP in this case) and I need your help. It's working but I want to know if I'm using it the right way with Hibernate, or if there are better ways to do it, and if my Spring Boot project structure is correct.

EDIT : It's working even if I remove the class `HikariCPConfig`, how can I know if connection pools are working or not?

The project is as follow :

```
- BankManager
   src/main/java
     |
     |__com.manager
        |__BankManagerApplication.java
        |__HikariCPConfig.java
     |__com.manager.dao
        |__ClientRepository.java
     |__com.manager.entities
        |__Client.java
     |__com.manager.service
        |__ClientServiceImpl.java
        |__ClientServiceInterface.java

   src/main/resources
     |__application.properties
```

BankManagerApplication.java :

```
@SpringBootApplication

    public class BankManagerApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {    
            ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(BankManagerApplication.class, args);
            ClientServiceInterface service = ctx.getBean(ClientServiceInterface.class);
            service.addClient(new Client("client1"));
            service.addClient(new Client("client2"));
            }
    }
```

HikariCPConfig.java :

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
class HikariCPConfig {

   @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
   private String user;

   @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
   private String password;

   @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
   private String dataSourceUrl;

   @Value("${spring.datasource.dataSourceClassName}")
   private String dataSourceClassName;

   @Value("${spring.datasource.poolName}")
   private String poolName;

   @Value("${spring.datasource.connectionTimeout}")
   private int connectionTimeout;

   @Value("${spring.datasource.maxLifetime}")
   private int maxLifetime;

   @Value("${spring.datasource.maximumPoolSize}")
   private int maximumPoolSize;

   @Value("${spring.datasource.minimumIdle}")
   private int minimumIdle;

   @Value("${spring.datasource.idleTimeout}")
   private int idleTimeout;

   @Bean
   public HikariDataSource primaryDataSource() {
       Properties dsProps = new Properties();
       dsProps.put("url", dataSourceUrl);
       dsProps.put("user", user);
       dsProps.put("password", password);
       dsProps.put("prepStmtCacheSize",250);
       dsProps.put("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit",2048);
       dsProps.put("cachePrepStmts",Boolean.TRUE);
       dsProps.put("useServerPrepStmts",Boolean.TRUE);

       Properties configProps = new Properties();
          configProps.put("dataSourceClassName", dataSourceClassName);
          configProps.put("poolName",poolName);
          configProps.put("maximumPoolSize",maximumPoolSize);
          configProps.put("minimumIdle",minimumIdle);
          configProps.put("minimumIdle",minimumIdle);
          configProps.put("connectionTimeout", connectionTimeout);
          configProps.put("idleTimeout", idleTimeout);
          configProps.put("dataSourceProperties", dsProps);

      HikariConfig hc = new HikariConfig(configProps);
      HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource(hc);
      return ds;
   }
}
```

ClientServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class ClientServiceImpl implements ClientServiceInterface {

    @Autowired
    ClientRepository clientRepository; // this class extends JPARepository

    @Override
    public Client addClient(Client c) {
        return clientRepository.save(c);
    }
}
```

application.properties :

```
server.port = 8888
spring.jpa.databasePlatform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

spring.datasource.dataSourceClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bank_manager
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.poolName=SpringBootHikariCP
spring.datasource.maximumPoolSize=5
spring.datasource.minimumIdle=3
spring.datasource.maxLifetime=2000000
spring.datasource.connectionTimeout=30000
spring.datasource.idleTimeout=30000
spring.datasource.pool-prepared-statements=true
spring.datasource.max-open-prepared-statements=250
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You project structure is standard, so it's correct.

About Hikari:

Hikari is indeed a great choice for pooling. I'm used to work with Hikari successfully by using a smaller set of params you are applying in your case, but if it's working for you that's fine.
For more info about Hikaru setup, I recommend reading the [official wiki](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/Configuration), if you haven't already.

About property loading:

You can make use of some SpringBoot features to read the DB parameters and apply into your runtime Beans with less code. Like:

In application.properties (define a custom prefix 'myproject.db' for your pool params)
`myproject.db.dataSourceClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
myproject.db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bank_manager
myproject.db.username=root
... and the other params below`

Create a Spring Configuration class

```
@Configuration
public class MyDBConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "myProjectDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myproject.db")
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        //This will activate Hikari to create a new DataSource instance with all parameters you defined with 'myproject.db'
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
}
```

In your ClientRepository class:

```
@Repository
public class ClientRepository {

    //The code below is optional, but will work if you want to use jdbctemplate tied to the DataSource created above. By default all Hibernate Sessions will take the DataSource generated by Spring
    @Bean(name = "myProjectJdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("myProjectDataSource") DataSource dataSource){
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
}
```

There are other options to manage the DataSource beans creation if you are going to use 2 or more different Databases. You can vary the properties prefix for the other databases and annotate 1 Datasource only as @Primary, which is mandatory when you have more than 1 DataSources in Spring context

Comment: Thanks, that was great help.